# Set Mandrill Template Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mandrill

I'm trying to send a Mandrill email in the default Laravel 4 Mailer, and I want to set the template and send the data to Mandrill. I'd rather not use a local file in my Laravel, I have this all set up to work inside of Mandrill. This is how I have it set in Laravel:

```
    Mail::send('emails.test',[],function($message)
    {
        $message->to(Input::get('email'), 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
    return
```

This sends an email from my "test" view inside of "emails" like it should. In vanilla PHP using the Mandrill library this would work to send to the template I want.

```
$message = array(
'subject' => 'Subject redacted',
'from_email' => $main_email,
'to' => array(array('email' => $to_email)),
'merge_vars' => array(array(
    'rcpt' => $to_email,
    'vars' =>
    array(
        array(
            'name' => 'DETAIL',
            'content' => $detail),
            array(
            'name' => 'ERROR_AMOUNT',
            'content' => '$'.$trans_amount)
            ,
            array(
            'name' => 'CO_NAME',
            'content' => $business_name),

            array(
            'name' => 'SMS',
            'content' => $sms)
))));

$template_name = 'Test Email';

$template_content = array(
array(
    'name' => 'main',
    )
);

$response = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is possible using `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer`.  It looks like the [Mandrill transport](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e60ea917ab862254a6db37fa9cb8933138c1e73c/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MandrillTransport.php#L52-L66) specifically uses the [`send-raw`](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-raw) Mandrill API endpoint.

This leaves you with two options: Implement your own transport and work within the `Mailer`, or work outside the `Mailer` system.  If you're going to go with the latter, you'd probably be best off just using the official library.

If you want to implement your own transport, take a look at the [`Swift_Transport`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/2b9af56cc676c338d52fca4c657e5bdff73bb7af/lib/classes/Swift/Transport.php) interface.  It's not going to be a perfect match, since you're attempting to do something that the `Mailer` was never intended to do, but with enough hacking, you could get something up and running. You'd probably need to use undefined members on the `Message` class, like:

```
$message->template = "template_name";
$message->content = array(/* content here */);
$message->message = array(/* message here */);

// MandrilTemplateTransport.php
public function send(Swift_Mime_Message $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
{
    $this->messages->send($message->template, $message->content, $message->message);
}
```

This is absolutely less than ideal, but a workable solution.  I'd vote that you just use the Mandrill library outside of the `Mailer` system.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the case. Upon further thought, there doesn't seem to be a compelling reason not to just roll my own template in Laravel - there's a couple little things that I'd prefer Mandrill to handle but nothing major.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons to use a template hosted on Mandrill. Primarily speed and bandwidth. If you're sending off a million templated e-mails, that's a million you have to render within PHP and a million you have to send over the network as the body to mandrill.

Comment: Just to add to @datashaman's comment, depending on what you're doing, there's also a huge advantage to non-devs being able to add and edit the templates via mandrill vs. requiring dev time/experience/a dev environment to edit the code itself

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, you could set the X-MC-MergeVars and X-MC-Template headers using Laravel's Mandrill functions.

```
Mail::send('emails.test', [], function($message) use ($mergevars)
{
    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-MergeVars', json_encode($mergevars));
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-Template', 'my-template');

    $message->to(Input::get('email'), 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Note that I haven't tested this - just going by what I read here: [Using SMTP Headers to customize your messages](http://mandrill.zendesk.com/entries/21688056).

You might need to use something other than addTextHeader - check with the Swiftmailer documentation to work out how to add the correct header type for the data you are setting.

Comment: @Mattias confirmed. You need to create the 'emails.test' view, but the email that fires is the template specified via the headers.

Comment: HOWEVER – smtp headers are limited to 1000 chars, so you won't be able to hand unlimited data to the template that way. See https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-#provide-merge-data-using-smtp-headers

Comment: Thanks for this. Two things:

1. `X-MC-Temmplate` has two `m`s in it.
2. You can add more than 1000 characters, you just need to add multiple headers.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answers, as it's more practical and doesn't require gambs. +1